# Insert Javascript in file_get_contents() php

Tags: php, javascript, insert, file-get-contents, inject

Is there a way to insert a javascript at the end of the `file_get_contents()`  ?

I don't mean adding to the output of the function, the javascript. What I want is to put a script at the end of the website I'm getting from the `file_get_contents()`.

Is like using a extension of chrome, which inserts a javascript at the end of the website. But in my case I want the function `file_get_contents($url)` to output directly everything (the website + javascript inserted).

Is there a way to use cUrl in this situation ?

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with manually adding the JavaScript?

Comment: Use [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to load the HTML and insert your tag.

Comment: The thing is that by inserting that javascript you wil be able to change the content of the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to use `*_replace` functions on the retrieved code, or use DOM classes to alter the code. There is no way to modify `file_get_contents` itself to add code

```
$script =<<<END
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/mysscript.js"></script>
   </body>
END;
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html = str_replace("</body>",$script,$html);
```

This assumes the content being grabbed has full html code, mainly includes the `</body>` tag

Comment: in what way doesnt it work, just saying it doesnt work doesnt help.

Comment: @AlejandroMorais, forgot to add $html as the last argument on str_replace, edited answer to reflect, that might be why it didnt work.

Comment: Nope. I mean that works, but the thing is that javascript should change the content of the page and it does not change. Other than that, the code works...

Comment: then there is a problem with your javascript. have you looked in the javascript console to see if there are errors? That problem should be put into a different question.